# How would I override misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css

Tags: javascript

I have theming being automatically applied by misc/jquery.ui.theme.css that I need to modify. I am using Views Accordian plugin in an instance of EVA for a FAQ category.

What is the Drupal way to override some of the css in this instance?

I read the "How to override a theme function?" but I don't think it would work in this case, I could be wrong.

Comment: CSS is all about specificity, so you should easily be able to override styles just using that

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add comments, but here is my two cents. In addition to Clive's comment, take a look at the `weight` and `group` option being used in `drupal_add_css`, in `views_accordion.module`. You can implement your own stylesheet here and assign a `CSS_THEME` for its `group` and a larger `weight` number than that of `views_accordion`, which I'm pretty sure would have used `CSS_DEFAULT` instead. Here are the docs page. [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Answer (score 0):

I  ended up using theme roller for the jquery parts I needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question as asked? Could you elaborate a bit more, so others could understand what you did?

Comment: #1 it is my question.  #2 since the specific css in this case is directly related to a jquery element,  I found that I don't have to reinvent the wheel.  There is a themeroller for jQuery at http://jquery.com/themeroller/